# Android ActionBar not changing background color

Tags: android, background, android-actionbar, themes, android-actionbar-compat

I am trying to change the background color of my action bar but it doesnt change. My app is using the AppCompat theme if that affects anything.

Here is my theme that is being used. My app points to use this theme so that is not the problem

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- Action Bar Styles -->
<style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="background">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Comment: are you also using **AppTheme** in manifest?

Comment: @waqaslam yup. am i doing something wrong in this code?

Comment: AFAIR <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item> is missing for API > 11. Please refer to https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html for details

Comment: @AlexanderZhak i am using the support action bar with gingerbread

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your ActionBar style, delete the android:background, only keep the background attribute. Also make sure to implement your AppTheme in the application tag or in the activities extending the action bar in your AndroidManifest.xml file. I've also added the "@style/" attribute before Widget.AppCompat since its a default style defined in the android library.

Your code should look like this :

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- Action Bar Styles -->
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">#0000ff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: pay attention to use both " **android:** actionBarStyle" and "actionBarStyle" names for compatibility same with background namespace

Comment: All of the tutorials I found had BOTH `android:actionBarStyle` AND `android:background`. Even ChatGPT gave those in its example. Android themes are the most cancerous part of Android programming and make me want to commit acts of violence. NONE of the names make sense.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry did you want `DayNight` or `Light` or `Dark` or `Light.DarkActionBar` and is it `Material3` or `AppCompat`, so annoying! Is `DayNight` both light and dark at the same time? I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can se this from code as well

ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(newcolor));

Just in case your xml is not working

Comment: I want to have it in XML form so i can use the color app-wide and i dont have to keep adding that line to every activity.

Comment: here you go 
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>  One of the reasons it is not working is because you have wrong parent for the style tag

Answer (score 0):

According to this link, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#background
it doesn't seem to take color resource, so you either give it a hex color value or create a drawable that uses the color you want. You could try the following alternative to see if it works.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- Action Bar Styles -->
<style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#0000ff</item>
    <item name="background">#0000ff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Using build tool 21.1.2, it doesn't allow giving color directly to themes. You *have* to give it using `@color` or `@drawable`.